# Distance calculation on map causing NumberFormatException

Tags: android, google-maps-android-api-2

On some mobile devices, calculating distance on map is causing `NumberFormatException`. Any way how to fix it other than try catch and not show it? I got NumberFormatException right from SphericalUtil.computeDistanceBetween function so I cant even convert it to String instantly. It will just crash the app as soon as that function returns value because it suppose to be Double but its some weird Double with comma instead of dot

```
fun updateDistance(){
        val loc = activity.currentLocation?.let { ll-> item.center.distanceTo(ll) }?.round(2)
        App.log("updateDistance: $loc")
        val formatted = loc?.let { if (loc < 1000) "$loc m" else "${(loc/1000).round(2)} km"  }
        distanceTxt.text = formatted?: ""
    }
fun LatLng.distanceTo(loc: LatLng) = SphericalUtil.computeDistanceBetween(this, loc)
```

Result:

```
updateDistance: 189332.39 (My phone - working great)
updateDistance: 189332,39 (Other phones - causing NumberFormatException)
```

Update: Issue is not with GoogleMaps function but Kotlin had to update something in their round function for Doubles. Because Kotlin function made to round doubles is causing it.

```
fun Double.round(decimals: Int = 2): Double = String.format("%.${decimals}f", this).toDouble()
```

This is causing exception for some reason. (Worked perfectly fine before). Even if I make adjustment to have dot instead of comma in my `Double` variable.

I recently updated Kotlin version because of Gradle so there can be some bug on their end with format function.

Comment: Yes, different countries, different decimal separators. Your code should handle it. The same with money amounts. $ 10.50 or € 10,50.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [replace](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.text/replace.html) function for the result.

Can you try this once.

```
fun updateDistance(){
 var doubleValue = 0.0
        val loc = activity.currentLocation?.let { ll-> item.center.distanceTo(ll) }?.round(2)
        doubleValue = loc.toString().replace(',', '.').toDouble()
    
        App.log("updateDistance: $doubleValue")

           val formatted = doubleValue.let { if (doubleValue.toInt()  < 1000) "$doubleValue  m" else "${(doubleValue /1000).roundToInt()} km"  }

        distanceTxt.text = formatted?: ""
    }
fun LatLng.distanceTo(loc: LatLng) = SphericalUtil.computeDistanceBetween(this, loc)
```